# the first time I start fileZilla it gives me an error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: filezilla

```
Connecting to server 
Trying to reconnect in 5 seconds
Error: Connection to server lost...
Connecting to server
Error, could not connect to server
Trying to reconnect in 5 seconds
Connecting to server 
Error, could not connect to server
Trying to reconnect in 5 seconds
Connecting to server 
Trying to reconnect in 5 seconds
Error: Connection to server lost..
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your antivirus/firewall blocks connection from your PC to the server, or the server doesn't accept incoming connections. [This](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=8341) might be your issue.

Edit: I'm assuming you're using the correct IP/address for the server, that would be the first thing to check.

Comment: That still doens't work. I still get the same error.